# Parsing mysql with html camp to xml

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I'm trying to parse data from mysql to xml. To use it for create markers on a Google Map.
But I have a problem.
When in the column of mysql I use html like  it crashes.

Mi code is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mapas";
$resultado = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado);


header("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
echo '<markers xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">';
do{
echo'<marker id="'.$row["id"].'" lat="'.$row["lat"].'" lng="'.$row["lng"].'" title="'.$row["title"].'" content="'.$row["content"].'" icon="'.$row["icon"].'"/>';
}while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado));
echo '</markers>';

?>
```

When I access to the page to see the xml the problem shown is:

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 1 at column 137: Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes
>   values Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

In Mysql the structure of the column is: Type: **Text, uf8-general-ci....**

If I use just text I have no problem at all.
¿Could you help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
echo'<marker id="'.$row["id"].'" lat="'.$row["lat"].'" lng="'.$row["lng"].'" title="'.$row["title"].'" content="'.$row["content"].'" icon="'.$row["icon"].'"/>';
```

to

```
echo'<marker id="'.$row["id"].'" lat="'.$row["lat"].'" lng="'.$row["lng"].'" title="'.$row["title"].'" content="'.$row["content"].'" icon="'.$row["icon"].'"></marker>';
```